# Programmatically take screen shot of part of the screen on Android

Tags: android, image-processing, screenshot, android-relativelayout

I'm doing an app where, at one point, the user will be able to make a composition with multiple ImageViews (which can be dragged and rotated) and then save the resulting combined image.

At first I thought I could just take a screenshot of the screen, which I was able to easily do with the following code:

```
private void takeScreenshot() {
    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

    try {
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, the output is literally everything on the screen, which not only includes areas that should be left out, but also includes the status bar.

Here's a visual representation of what I need:

[image: Needed area]

I need to take a screen shot (or otherwise combine the ImageViews in a single image file) of only the yellow part, throwing everything that's on the black parts out, cutting images if needed be.

The ImageViews will be added to a RelativeLayout that has the same size of the screen, as the user needs to be able to place parts of the ImageViews outside the cutting zone.

The yellow part being merely a background color and the black parts black overlays to show the user that part of the image will be left out.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Why screenshot at all?

Comment: You have to put your code so we can understand.

Comment: The reason I'm using a screenshot is because it sounds more easily doable than somehow processing the images inside the ImageViews with their position and rotation, though I might be wrong. Also, I've edited the question to be more clear on what I'm trying to do.